# How to create a cron job in cpanel to run a PHP file every hour?

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

First time I am creating a `cron` job in cpPanel to run a PHP file every hour.

My cron command is:

```
/usr/local/bin /home/simplemediaplaye/public_html/new.php
```

What things am I missing here? This file runs well manually, but not by a `cron` job. Can you suggest what I need to do to run my `cron` successfully?

Comment: This is not a programming nor technical question. Consider asking such questions in [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: You don't have php in your command. It should be /usr/local/bin/php (or wherever your php path is)

Answer (score 0):

Hello If I am not mistaking, you're missing the "-q" command and PHP ? see below:

`/usr/bin/php -q /home/simplemediaplaye/public_html/new.php`

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: thanks @andre3wap  ,but still cron job is not working.

Comment: Even though parameters are optional, Try this and grab the errror logs for the timeframe it ran:  php -q -f /home/simplemediaplaye/public_html/new.php